# API - Framework -Library

Tags: api, frameworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [API vs Toolkit vs FrameWork vs Libarary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453011/api-vs-toolkit-vs-framework-vs-libarary)

Can someone Explain the differences between an API, a Framework and a Library.
Some examples would be helpfull , specially for API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API (Application Programming Interface) - Allows you to use code in an already functional application in a stand-alone fasion.

Framework - Code that gives you base classes and interfaces for a certain task/application type, usually in the form of a design pattern. (Though not always)

Library - Related code that can be swapped in and out at will to accomplish tasks at a class level

Ref [`Ryan answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453011/api-vs-toolkit-vs-framework-vs-libarary/5463441#5463441)

Comment: Thanks,Can you also give some examples?

Comment: Sure, Api -> [Abstract Window Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Window_Toolkit), Framework -> [.Net Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19), Library -> [ASP.NET Ajax Library](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/download.ashx)

Comment: thanks a lot man, i will find out something with this.Some people in here seem quite hostile.